# Which current WebGL library supports most 3D model formats (and which ones)?

Tags: 3d, webgl, javascript, 3d-model

Searched a while but dont know which current WebGL solution supports the most 3d formats.
Also I need to know which 3d formats they support.

Are there any updated comparisons or tables with these information?

Something like copperlicht? An alternative?

we want to use the native formats directly so converting them manually always to json is not an option

Comment: What comes up when you search [JS 3D libraries](http://www.google.com/search?q=js+3d+libraries)? Is it that hard to do?

Comment: I need a comparison about the supported 3d formats. The library that supports most formats

Comment: searched for comparisons but no more infos about supported 3d model formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think best is not "choose solution that supports most formats".

Choosing a solution supporting the most used, readable, editable and mature formats (.dae and .x3d) is best

We now use [x3dom](https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom) for .x3d, [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) for .dae and .obj and [thingiview](https://github.com/tbuser/thingiview.js) for .stl

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Three.js is your choice, it supports: native json, obj, fbx, gltf, collada, babylon, stl, ply, vrml and many others.

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all?) engines have their own JSON-format and you use offline converters to get your data into the engine format. If you like support for many formats I would suggest using J3D as it uses Unity 3D as "converter". Unity can import all sorts of formats and thus J3D supports these.

https://github.com/drojdjou/J3D

Comment: we want to use the native formats directly so converting them manually always to json is not an option
also its about webgl and javascript, forcing the users to use unity is not an option

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if I know any better solution than writing the parsers yourself, and then you can pretty much use any framework of your liking :)

Answer (score 0):

I've started doing some web experiments using 3d technologies and I strongly recommend working with .obj or .fbx files, and using p5.js and/or three.js.
Anyways there is more than one way to make it work.
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/model