# Import 3D scan tool

Tags: 3d, webgl, blender

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which current WebGL library supports most 3d model formats (and which ones)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528917/which-current-webgl-library-supports-most-3d-model-formats-and-which-ones)

I need to do the following:

1. Import a 3d scan
2. Export it to something readable by webGL

Using a 3D tool, like Blender.

Does any one know what is the best tool to use ? I know Maya, 3D Max, Blender, Cinema 4D. are there any others ?

I need one that can perform the above actions, with the simplest way possible.

Comment: What file type does the 3d scan produce?

Comment: Thanks Jan Dvorak for answering, actually I don't have yet any concrete details, I was asked to search about this subject so I can decide what tool to use

Comment: Look into: what WebGL supports; what file type you get; how to convert from the latter to the former; depending on the tools available, this might be a two-step process. The best we can do is to find out what file formats WebGL supports and how to produce them from something standard. I believe WebGL does support something standard.

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528917/which-current-webgl-library-supports-most-3d-model-formats-and-which-ones